# How to set section numbering in [svmult]?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sv-classes

In my book I have automatically-numbered chapters and sections but when I type

```
\chapter{CHAP 1}
\section{SEC 1}
\subsection{SUBSEC 1}
\subsection{SUBSEC 2}
```

I receive a chapter with number 1, section with number 1, and subsections with numbers `1.1` and `1.2` but I'd like to have chapter numbered `1`, section numbered `1.1` and subsetions with numbers `1.1.1` and `1.1.2`. Please, can anyone can help me ?

My code is below:

```
\documentclass[envcountresetchap]{svmult}
\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float} %pakiet do obsługi obrazków
\usepackage{graphicx} %pakiet do dodawania obrazków
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        citecolor=blue,
        urlcolor=blue}


\title*{Title}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle

\preface
\lipsum

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{CHAP 1}
\section{SEC 1}

\subsection{SUBSEC 1}
\subsection{SUBSEC 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}`
 to the preamble.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
```

to the preamble, after the titling information. A complete example:

```
\documentclass[envcountresetchap]{svmult}

\title*{Title}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Another test subsection}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{Yet another test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]